# Why Djano forms fields value not rendering in html template for function based update view?

Tags: python, django

This is my update views:

```
def EditDoctor(request,slug=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
       obj = get_object_or_404(Doctor,slug=slug) 
       form = DoctorUpdateFrom(request.POST,instance=obj)
       if form.is_valid():
          
          form.save()
          return redirect('hospital:all-doctor') 
    else:
        form = DoctorUpdateFrom()
    context = {'doctor_form':form}

    return render (request,'hospital/edit-doctor.html', context)
```

The main problems I am not seeing any existing value in my forms. it's just rendering an empty forms.

Comment: Check if it should be 'DoctorUpdateForm'. If that is correct please provide the whole, or at least the relevant parts of the 'Doctor' Model and the 'DoctorUpdateFrom' as well as the result you actually see when calling the view.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the instance to the form in case of a GET request as well:

```
def EditDoctor(request,slug=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Doctor,slug=slug)  # 🖘 fetch the object for both paths
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = DoctorUpdateFrom(request.POST,instance=obj)
       if form.is_valid():
          
          form.save()
          return redirect('hospital:all-doctor') 
    else:
        form = DoctorUpdateFrom(instance=obj)  # 🖘 pass the instance to edit
    context = {'doctor_form':form}

    return render (request,'hospital/edit-doctor.html', context)
```

Comment: I also tried but didn't work `form = DoctorUpdateFrom(instance=obj)` my forms is updating but I am not seeing any existing value

Comment: @boyenec: nvm I found out what is wrong, you need to define `obj` outside the `if`.

Comment: Thanks. it worked

Comment: Only one question how to go back to profile page. something like this `return redirect('hospital:patient-details',request.slug)`???

Comment: @boyenec: you can use `redirect('hospital:patient-details',slug)`, but this is the slug of the doctor, not that of the patients, so `patient-details` does not look like the right view (or perhaps it is, but the name hints that it deals with a single patient).